# How do I use the telnet interface to my Zyxel router to enable Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, telnet

I have a pretty horrible Zyxel P-2812HNU-F1 router provided by my ISP which drops my Wifi some one to five times each day. It doesn't crash, it just decides to disable wifi.

I can log in to the web interface and reenable it, all the settings are still there, but it's a pain in the butt to do this.

I was thinking about having my server, which is tethered by ethernet, use expect and telnet to keep the connection up. Doing the scripting part on the Ubuntu side is trivial, but the Zyxel part is pretty confusing.

I simply can't figure out how to use their telnet CLI. I've looked for guides, but even those by Zyxel that come close (another 2812HNU which isn't "F1") differ wildly in their interface.

I'm looking for someone who has some experience in using the CLI on Zyxels, perhaps this particular model, who can guide me in a sequence of CLI commands that'll allow me to enable the WLAN interface.

Comment: have you try updating the firmware, it might solve this problem??

Comment: @chmod This is unfortunately beyond my capabilites. The ISP delivers the router locked, and manage firmware updates remotely. I know of a few others that have the same ISP and they also complain about the stability of the router. This is actually a replacement router I just received as the one I previously had (a Netgear one) became extremely unstable, too.

Comment: FWIW, it seems that if I keep a torrent client open and active on a device on the WLAN, the router stays up (so far). But this is hardly a solution ;D

Comment: Okay, it seems this ISP (Fullrate) is just basically crap in user support, hardware and stability so I'm gonna look for a better alternative. My hours are too valuable for this :) The thing threw the Wifi twelve times yesterday, LOL :D

Comment: This shouldn't be happening with this modem. Try to reset to factory settings, if the problems persists get an RMA from your provider.